# Java - split a string that can be pipe-delimited ("\\I"), comma-delimited (","), semicolon-delimited (";") and others

Tags: java, regex, string, split, delimiter

I'm trying to split a string that can delimited by any character or characters specified by the user eg comma, semicolon, and/or pipe. For cleanliness and flexibility, I'd ideally like these delims in an array (whether string or char or Regex, whatever works).

```
String[] stringsToSplit = {"alpha,bravo,charlie", "delta;echo;foxtrot", "golf|hotel|india", "juliet\nkilo\nlima"};
String[] acceptedNonEscapedDelims = {"," , ";"};
String[] acceptedEscapedDelims = {"\\|" , "\\n"};
```

I can only get it to work using a hardcoded Regex.

```
String[] values = string.split("\\n|\\||\\t|,|;");
```

Something about storing the regex in a string array is such that the following doesn't work.

```
String[] values = string.split(acceptedEscapedDelims[0]);
```

I could make a boolean flag for each possible delimiter and split using each one individually hardcoded, but this approach seems like hackery to me. For such a simple thing, it is also deceptively fiddly. If you handle each delimiter separately, a lot of special handling is needed: eg. testing for whether string contains a comma (before you try to split using comma) otherwise you get array elements of a single character.

Comment: *Question 1*: Can 1 string have multiple delimiters used (e.g. would `"A,B;C|D\nE"` be valid input and, if so, would it be split to 5 elements?). *Question 2*: What would happen for a string where the data actually contains a comma, e.g. `"'Dalton, Timothy';'Connery, Sean';"`?

Comment: `String[] values = string.split(acceptedEscapedDelims[0]);` works just fine: https://ideone.com/xLox9T

Answer (score 1):

You are splitting only with single character, so maybe try `[abcde]` ("one of") form instead of `a|b|c|d|e`. Demo:

`System.out.println( Arrays.toString( "a;b.c|d".split( "[;.|]") ));`

output:

`[a, b, c, d]`

Comment: Thanks for this killer_PL, I could do as you suggest, but as far as I see, this doesn't directly tackle the configurability question. I need the user to be able to dynamically specify which delimiters to use. I can get the delimiters and store them in an array, but then they don't work. How do I pass the delimiter(s) from the delim array into the regex?

Comment: @Julie Just concat delimiters by `StringBuilder`. Remember to escape chars like `"` or `]`

Comment: `code`String[] regularDelims = {",", ";"};
    String[] escapedDelims = {"\\|", "\n"};
    String[] stringsToSplit = {"alpha,bravo,charlie", "delta;echo;foxtrot", "golf|hotel|india", "juliet\nkilo\nlima"};

    String allDelims = "[";

        for (String delim : regularDelims) {
            allDelims += ("|"+delim);
        }

        for (String delim : escapedDelims) {
            allDelims += ("|\\"+ delim);
        }

        allDelims+="]";`code`

Comment: Thanks so much. I've just confirmed that the above does work; sorry the code tags don't seem to be used properly.